# windows form & design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

i am familier with mvc,mvp or mvvm patter. so i was searching google for implementing good design patter for win form apps. i found lots of article.few guys said mvc is good and few guys said mvp is perfect for win apps. i found a very small code which implement mvp in win apps. i go through the code and found that developer has to write lot of extra code to bind treeview or any control.

the code as follows

```
public interface IYourView
{
   void BindTree(Model model);
}

public class YourView : System.Windows.Forms, IYourView
{
   private Presenter presenter;

   public YourView()
   {
      presenter = new YourPresenter(this);
   }

   public override OnLoad()
   {
         presenter.OnLoad();
   }

   public void BindTree(Model model)
   {
       // Binding logic goes here....
   }
}

public class YourPresenter
{
   private IYourView view;

   public YourPresenter(IYourView view)
   { 
       this.view = view;
   }

   public void OnLoad()
   {
       // Get data from service.... or whatever soruce
       Model model = service.GetData(...);
       view.BindTree(model);
   }
}
```

please someone go through the code and help me to understand the flow because how code should be written in mvp patter that i dont know. thanks.

Comment: please reformat it - do not use `...`, but insert 4 white spaces before every line of code

Comment: i have been learning winforms patterns recently and would like to understand but I can't quit comprehend your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is already using the MVP pattern.

It declares an interface `IYourView` and a concrete class `YourView` that implements System.Windows.Form and this new interface.  Essentially what that is doing is creating a new form with the added requirement that it also implements the `BindTree()` method defined in `IYourView`.

The `YourView` class (form) then has a dependency of `YourPresenter` in order to hook up the `OnLoad` event with the presenter, although I'd do it where the presenter subscribes to the form's `OnLoad` event instead.

The presenter `YourPresenter` takes as a dependency an instance of YourView and it can then use that instance in the rest of its logic.

Now, to use that you would follow a process similar to this:

- Create a new instance of `YourView` (which then in turn creates the presenter)
- Implement logic in the presenter (ie- create `GetModel()`) to create the Model that you want to bind to the tree
- Call `view.BindTree(model)` in the presenter where model is what you just created in the previous step

So, create an instance of your view:

```
IYourView newView = new YourView();
```

Then in your presenter class:

```
Model model = GetModel();
newView.BindTree(model);
```